# When finding the absolute extrema of a multivariable function, why can't I find the boundary equation in terms of a variable instead of parametrizing

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I am given the function $F(x,y) = 2x^2+y^2-y$ and the boundary $x^2+y^2≤1$. After finding the critical points inside the boundary, to find the critical points on the boundary, I substituted $1-y^2$ in for $x^2$ into the equation, found the derivative, set it equal to 0, and found the critical points on the boundary.

My professor told me I couldn't do it that way and had to parametrize the function in terms of t in order to find the critical points on the boundary. Is he right? and why? I've seen both methods work online and I got the same answer as him.

Comment: In your new problem involving only $y \in [-1,1]$, did you remember to check what happens at the endpoints $y=\pm 1$? If not, your solution is incomplete. Also, it's a bit of a fluke that your approach works, since $F$ just happens to depend on $x^2$ rather than on $x$ itself.

Comment: Yes, I did make sure to check the endpoints at y = +-1. Also, wouldn't it not matter if it was x^2 or x because I could just solve for x anyways. I'm just not sure why some sites such as Paul's notes say that you can use the substitution method while others parameterize it.

Comment: OK, good. What I meant was just that it's lucky that you get the same value of $F$ for both solutions $x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$, otherwise you would have to consider the two cases separately. Which is nothing but parametrizing (parts of) the boundary using $y$ as the parameter, so I don't see that there's anything wrong with your approach.